# How to modify pixel data of cv::Mat in openCV?

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I basically tried some ways of modifying the pixel data from the questions already existing here. However, nothing is just working.

I am working on iOS OpenCV2.framework.

I've implemented the following method, but its not modifying the outputImage.

```
UIImage *inputUIImage = [UIImage imageName:@"someImage.png"];
UIImage *outputUIImage = nil;

cv::Mat inputImage = <Getting this from a method that converts UIImage to cv::Mat: Working properly>
cv::Mat outputImage; 

inputImage.copyTo(outputImage);

//processing...
for(int i=0; i < outputImage.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<outputImage.cols; j++)
    {
        Vec4b bgrColor = outputImage.at<Vec4b>(i,j);

        //converting the 1st channel <assuming the sequence to be BGRA>
        // to a very small value of blue i.e. 1 (out of 255)
        bgrColor.val[0] = (uchar)1.0f;
    }
}

outputUIImage = <Converting cv::Mat to UIImage via a local method : Working properly> 

self.imageView1.image = inputUIImage;
self.imageView2.image = outputUIImage;
//here both images are same in colour. no changes.
```

Can anyone let me know what am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are copying the reference that `outputImage.at<Vec4b>(i,j)` returns into a local variable bgrColor and modify that one. So nothing in outputImage actually gets modified. What you want to do is to directly modify the reference returned by `Mat::at`.

Solutions:

```
Vec4b& bgrColor = outputImage.at<Vec4b>(i,j);
bgrColor.val[0] = (uchar)1.0f;
```

or

```
outputImage.at<Vec4b>(i,j)[0] = (uchar)1.0f;
```

Comment: but here in your solutions, even you have written the same code as I did for the 1st one.. and its not working.. however, I will try the second one.

Comment: sorry. typo. Fixed now

Comment: hmm I see.. now its a reference.

Comment: done! both ways are working now.. I previously thought that the returning Vec4b should already be a pointer, since there is no explicit copy operation visibly seen in code.. but damn! no "&" behind the data-type results in copy operation. 8o